# C# Expression composition

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, iqueryable

Say I have two classes:

```
public class Parent {
   public Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to write a function that filters Parents by their child's name containing a substring.

```
public IQueryable<Parent> ParentsChildNameMatches(IQueryable<Parent> parents, string word)
{
   return parents.Where(parent => parent.Child.Name.Contains(word));
}
```

If I then want to pull out that Expression so I can reuse the Child contains check elsewhere

```
public Expression<Func<Child, bool> ChildNameMatches(string word)
{
   return child => child.Name.Contains(word));
}
```

How do I then use that in my .Where such that I can rewrite ParentsChildNameMatches?

```
public IQueryable<Parent> ParentsChildNameMatches(IQueryable<Parent> parents, string word)
{
   return parents.Where( // how to leverage ChildNameMatches?
}
```

Comment: Actually, shouldn't your `ChildNameMatches` accept `Parent`, not `Child`, and be `return parent => parent.Child. ...`?

Comment: Well, my goal here is that I can then reuse the ChildNameMatches expression for either Child classes by themselves, or when there are other parent classes with Child properties.

Comment: If that particular method `ChildNameMatches` is defined in the `Child` class, then you can add another one with the signature I suggested for the `Parent` class, otherwise you won't be able to directly use it in that `.Where()` invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, given an `Expression<Func<Child, bool>>`, and the fact that you can create an expression from `Parent` to `Child` via the `Child` property in the `Parent` class, you want to obtain a `Expression<Func<Parent, bool>>`.

You can do this manually using the [expression trees API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/), or you can use some 3rd party libraries like [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) like this:

```
public IQueryable<Parent> ParentsChildNameMatches(IQueryable<Parent> parents, string word)
{
    var childExpression = ChildNameMatches(word);

    Expression<Func<Parent, bool>> expression = p => childExpression.Invoke(p.Child);

    expression = expression.Expand();

    return parents.Where(expression);
}
```

LinqKit provides the `Invoke` method that allows you to compose expressions together. It also provides the `Expand` method which flattens the resultant expression.

You can read more about this here: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

*UPDATED*: previous code did not work. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, After the update, this works for me. Out of curiosity, when would you need to additionally use linqkit.entityframework?

Comment: I really don't know. Maybe you can find such information on the library's project site.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your lambdas with `Invoke`

```
public static IQueryable<Parent> ParentsChildNameMatches(IQueryable<Parent> parents, string word)
{
    var childPredicate = ChildNameMatches(word);

    var parent = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Parent), "parent");
    var parentPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Parent, bool>>(
        Expression.Invoke(
            childPredicate, 
            Expression.Property(parent, "Child")),
        parent);

    return parents.Where(parentPredicate);
}
```

This code will create a new expression `parent => parent.Child` and use it as paremeter to `childPredicate`